# Website maintenance landing page

Tags: tomcat, web, incapsula

This is a pretty lame question to begin with. We have a web application hosted with a cloud provider with the layers that the traffic needs to pass though.

A WAF ( Cloud hosted ) --> Load balancer ( Cloud provided ) --> Tomcat (instance )

We don't have a web server sitting in front of Tomcat.
Wanted to know how others manage site outages, in terms on setting up a maintenance page and ideally where it should be sitting. 
When i mention site maintenance it's bringing Tomcat down. 
Apologies upfront on any ambiguities.

cheers
OSP

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using Incapsula, you can use their Custom error page (available for Ent clients only)and once the Tomcat is down the users will see the Incapsula error page (customised by you).

Answer (score 0):

Either using Incapsula's custom error option or just point the DNS to another static origin like Cloudfront or S3